# Showing a circle is isomorphic to the union of itself and another disjoint circle

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This question in Set Theory is as follows:

> Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be disjoint circles. Show that $C_1 \sim C_1 \cup C_2$

I think figuring this out would help me with the rest of my homework on isomorphisms. This is meant to be a warm-up question but I'm unsure what to do. Maybe use the Cantor-Bernstein-Schroeder Theorem at some point?

Any advice is helpful!

Comment: Maybe you can find a bjiection between a circle and $[0,1)$?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done directly, without the Cantor–Schröder–Bernstein theorem.

Let $f_1 : [0,2\pi) \to C_1$ and $f_2 : [0,2\pi) \to C_2$ be bijections defined in your favourite way, e.g. by letting $f_i(\theta)$ be the point on $C_i$ at angle $\theta$ anticlockwise from some fixed point).

We obtain a bijection $f : [0,2\pi) \to C_1 \cup C_2$ by defining
$$f(\theta) = \begin{cases} f_1(2\theta) & \text{if } 0 \le \theta < \pi \\ f_2(2(\theta-\pi)) & \text{if } \pi \le \theta < 2\pi \end{cases}$$

But then $f \circ f_1^{-1} : C_1 \to C_1 \cup C_2$ is a bijection.